# rbt setup-repo returns with error

Tags: git, github, review-board

I am using git as my code repository. While trying to setup the review board server form git cmd line rbt returns with the below error:

**ERROR: Could not load SCM Client "git": [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
ERROR: The current directory does not contain a checkout from a supported source code repository.**

I have some files modified on the client.

I am new to git, so I am not sure if its to do with some error in git installation or not. Although my git commands are all working fine.

rbt version is 0.7.3
Any pointers what is going wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can try `rbt setup-repo -d` for debugging logs; it may show you the problem.

The problem may be you don't have a repository added on review board or the repository addition may not be correct.

you can check this [review board wiki](https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/1.5/admin/management/repositories/) for more information about repository adding

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. Reason was that when I installed svn, I did not select the CLI option. (By default CLI tools are not selected when you install svn). I re-installed again and it worked.