# ERROR: The current directory does not contain a checkout from a supported source code repository

Tags: git, perforce, rbtools

I am getting the below error while running command `rbt post <changelist-number>`.

> ERROR: The current directory does not contain a checkout from a supported source code repository.

I have correctly setup P4 client.

If there any leads on how to resolve this, it will be great help.

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31853358/7976758)?

Answer (score 1):

```
It might be because you are running this command from different location.

1.run following command
p4 info
2.Above command will return you
Client root: /user/xyx/abc
3.Navigate to that folder 
4.Run rbt post <changelist-number> from the client root folder
```